# How to turn off development error messages in Phoenix framework?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Right now I'm getting nice error messages from my Phoenix server:

[image: Nice phoenix error message]

However, I'm using Phoenix as an API, and these error messages show up as a large chunk of unreadable html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>UndefinedFunctionError at GET /api/v1/sessions/test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style>/*! normalize.css v4.2.0 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */html{font
      ...1300+ lines...
```

Is there a way to turn this off so my development server spits out JSON error messages instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `config/dev.exs` in the web endpoint configuration main section set `debug_errors` value to `false`:

```rb
config :my_app, MyAppWeb.Endpoint,
  # http: [port: 4000],  # or like
  debug_errors: false,   # ⇐ HERE 
  ...
```